# Saturation of uncertainty principle of Fourier analysis

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis, normal-distribution, fourier-transform

The uncertainty principle in Fourier analysis is given by the inequality
$$
\sigma_t \sigma_\omega \geq \frac{1}{2}
$$

It is a well known result that this lower bound is saturated exactly only in the case of a Gaussian spectrum.

However, I read somewhere (I can't really find the reference) that it can be proved that it will be nearly saturated, i.e. there exists a constant $c_1$ of order $1$ such that
$$
\sigma_t \sigma_\omega = c_1
$$
when the spectrum is unimodal and without long tails.

Can anyone provide some evidence of this? Is there any known proof of this fact, and any estimate of this $c_1$?

Comment: What does "order $1$" mean here? There aren't any other parameters.

Comment: At the beginning, this is the uncertainty principle of quantum mechanics ...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan it's not clear to me either, but let say it is some constant

Comment: But it's always going to be some constant as long as $\sigma_t$ and $\sigma_w$ are finite.